# What does "pinned" mean in this case?

Tags: c, libevent

When I read source code of libevent,
I saw this comment but I can't understand the meaning of "pinned"?

```
    /* Make sure that none of the chains we need to copy from is pinned. */
remaining = size - chain->off;
EVUTIL_ASSERT(remaining >= 0);
for (tmp=chain->next; tmp; tmp=tmp->next) {
    if (CHAIN_PINNED(tmp))
        goto done;
    if (tmp->off >= (size_t)remaining)
        break;
    remaining -= tmp->off;
}
```

Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Maybe the definition of `CHAIN_PINNED` has some documentation/explanation.

Comment: Not really, closest I got is http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/external/bsd/libevent/dist/evbuffer-internal.h#L242 : "Pin a single buffer chain using a given flag. A pinned chunk may not be moved or freed until it is unpinned." That is a common usage of "pin": Mark a piece of data to stay in memory. As in "stick a pin in it so it cannot be moved".

Comment: Show us the definition of `CHAIN_PINNED`, maybe we can help you then

Comment: Thank you^^. So under this case, if a buffer chain is pinned, when I call this code above, I can't get even a byte data in the pinned buffer chain, right?

Answer (score 0):

Pinned in this case just means that the `evbuffer_chain` is currently in uses for reading or for writing. By looking at the definition of `CHAIN_PINNED` and definition of `EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_ANY` , `EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_W`,  and 'EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_R' you'll see that it's checking the evenbuffer_chain's flags for it's in use for reading or writing as seen below:

[buffer.c](http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/external/bsd/libevent/dist/buffer.c#L140):

```
#define CHAIN_PINNED(ch)  (((ch)->flags & EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_ANY) != 0)
```

[evbuffer-internal.h](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/ipc/chromium/src/third_party/libevent/evbuffer-internal.h):

```
#define EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_R   0x0010
#define EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_W   0x0020
#define EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_ANY (EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_R|EVBUFFER_MEM_PINNED_W)
```

You can further see when these flags are set in the code like [here in the source for writing](http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/external/bsd/libevent/dist/buffer_iocp.c#L209) and [here in the source for reading](http://users.sosdg.org/~qiyong/mxr/source/external/bsd/libevent/dist/buffer_iocp.c#L247).